# how to find class with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<hknbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="padding_25 font_7 bold xicolor_07" style="width:30%">

                date

            </td>
            <td class="font_34 xicolor_42">

                19 Eylül 2013

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10px" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bgcolor_09" style="height:5px" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10px" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="padding_25 font_7 bold xicolor_07" style="width:30%">

                Size

            </td>
            <td class="font_34 xicolor_42">
               650 cm
```

Classes names same, classes in the same table. 
How can I find correct data? Example; if "date" doesn't exist in `<td class="padding_25 font_7 bold xicolor_07>`, you don't pull date and find next data.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup(html_code).findAll("td", {"class" : "font_34"})`

Comment: "BeautifulSoup(html_code).findAll("td", {"class" : "font_34"})" I know that. This is a problem. Example; if date doesn't exist,  I pull other data in wrong place.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to me. what is `<hknbody>` tag?

Comment: So then just check if you catch a date or not?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTML and you can change it, you should be using [semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) to markup your elements with class, id, or name attributes that describe the meaning of the data, not its appearance. Then you will have an unambiguous way of selecting the required tags.

As it is all you have to do something like this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

date_tag = soup.find('td', text=re.compile('^\s*date\s*$'))    # find first <td> containing text "date"
if date_tag:
    date_value = date_tag.find_next_sibling('td').text.strip()

>>> print date_value
19 Eylül 2013
```